# Flex image row: remove unwanted letterboxing

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I need a row of images all resized to the min(200px, image height) preserving aspect ratios. Flexbox almost works:

```
.img-row {
    --img-max-height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 5px;
}

.img-row > * {
    max-height: var(--img-max-height);
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
}

img {
    object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

[image: with letterboxing]

Please note the letterboxing around the squares.

The problem can be fixed by setting each image's `max-height` to the smallest height among all images:

```
for (const r of document.querySelectorAll('.img-row')) {
    const h = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
        r.children, (h, c) => Math.min(h, c.naturalHeight || c.offsetHeight), 200);
    if (h < 200) {
        r.style.setProperty('--img-max-height', `${h}px`);
    }
}
```

[image: without letterboxing]

Image widths are unchanged, and there is no rescaling in the flex direction, only letterboxing is removed.

Why flexbox can't figure out the right height on its own? Is there a pure CSS solution to this problem?

Here is the complete example page with canvas generated images (the issue is reproducible with real images having the same sizes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flex Image Row</title>
  <style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        display: flex;
        background-color: grey;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .img-row {
        --img-max-height: 200px;
        display: flex;
        column-gap: 5px;
        background-color: white;
        max-width: 800px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .img-row > * {
        max-height: var(--img-max-height);
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 0;
    }

    img {
        object-fit: scale-down;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="img-row"></div>

  <script type="module">
    async function squareWithBackground(width, height, colour) {
        const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(width, height);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.fillStyle = colour;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        const side = Math.floor(Math.min(width, height) / 2);
        ctx.clearRect((width - side) / 2, (height - side) / 2, side, side);

        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(await canvas.convertToBlob());
        return img;
    }

    const imgRow = document.querySelector('.img-row');
    imgRow.append(
        await squareWithBackground(200, 200, 'red'),
        await squareWithBackground(200, 134, 'orange'),
        await squareWithBackground(200, 120, 'green'),
        await squareWithBackground(640, 480, 'blue'),
        await squareWithBackground(640, 480, 'purple'),
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No pure CSS solution as far as I am aware. My solution uses Javascript to calculate the height of `.img-row` based on the sum of the intrinsic aspect ratios of each of the images. The result is that the images all fit into the flex container, at a consistent height, and at their intrinsic aspect ratio.

```js
let debounceTimer

const recalc = () => {
  const imgRow = document.querySelector('.img-row')
  const images = Array.from(imgRow.children)

  const colGap = 5   // 5 pixels, to match the column-gap on .img-row
  const totalGap = (images.length - 1) * colGap

  let ratioSum = 0
  images.forEach(img => {
    ratioSum += img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight
    img.style.opacity = "1"
  })
  imgRow.style.height = ((imgRow.offsetWidth - totalGap) / ratioSum) + 'px'
}

// run this when all the images have finished loading, so we have access to their intrinsic sizes
addEventListener('load', () => {
  recalc()
})

addEventListener('resize', () => {
  clearTimeout(debounceTimer)
  if (document.readyState === "complete")
    debounceTimer = setTimeout(recalc, 200)
})
```

```css
body {
  background: silver;
  margin: 1em;
}

.img-row {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;       /* initial value, overridden by script */
  transition: 300ms;
}

.img-row > img {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;         /* initial value, overridden by script */
}
```

```html
<p>Wait for it ... images can be slow to load ...</p>
<div class="img-row">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" title="1:1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" title="3:2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180" title="16:9">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/240/180" title="4:3">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/99/176" title="9:16"> <!-- portrait -->
</div>
```

See the full effect by using the **full page** link after running the snippet.

Comment: It's no simpler than the 7 lines of JS from my post.

Comment: Mine is not necessarily a better solution, but it does include automatic recalculation when the viewport size changes.