# How to adjust side-by-side images to be same height and still fit current screen size?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, autosize

I am currently working on making side-by-side images dynamic so they can stay side-by-side no matter what screen they are on. However, these images also have different ratios; so, I am using the flex display type to keep them the same height.

Here is my current HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <img src=(thefirstimage) alt="A picture of me."/>
</div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src=(thesecondimage) alt="Another picture of me."/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    float: left;
    height: 40vh;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

At this point on my computer screen, the images are properly side-by-side at the same height despite the different aspect ratios. However, when I view the same page on my phone one image moves on top of the other.

So to sum up, the two problems I'm trying to get to work together are:

- Resizing side-by-side images to be the same height
- Keeping that no matter what the screen size is

I saw two other posts on here that cover those both separately, I just can't get it to work together.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: You are mixing a lot of techniques: table, flex and float. These do not work well together! It's also not so clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. The images should *always* remain next to each other no matter how small the screen? Should they shrink or should they overflow (creating a horizontal scrollbar) ? And what should happen if the images have different ratios? Should a part be cut off? Or should the image be distorted?

Comment: The images do have different aspect ratios, yes, and I want them to have the same height no matter what. I'd like the images to change size based on the width of the window if possible. Currently, the images will shrink and grow based on the height of the window; however, on windows with a narrow width (such as a phone) the images end up getting stacked on top of each other - one moves to the second line.

Comment: At the heart of what you have written is a great question, so kudos for that. But what you have actually written is not terribly precise; as you can see by the clarifications which we’ve had to ask you for. To help the community, your next step should be to **edit your question** to improve it. At least take your clarifying comments and add those into the question. But a stack snippet which demonstrates your efforts is what would really make this “a question for the ages” ... one which stands the test of time and is useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve asked for a solution which allows you to fill the width of the viewport with two images side-by-side with the same height but differing aspect ratios. I’m going to give you a solution to put *any* number of images of varying aspect-ratios side-by-side.

The first part of the solution is a flexbox with a fixed height, with the flex items (images) each styled with 100% height. This gives you an image strip with all images having the same height, and with their width determined by their aspect ratio.

Let’s try with five images with aspect ratios as follows:

- 1:1
- 3:2
- 16:9
- 4:3
- 9:16

If the flexbox is short (has a small height) it will render like this:

[image]

Here is a working snippet to demonstrate the solution so far. Make sure after running it you use the **full page** link to get the full effect.

```js
document.getElementById('i1').addEventListener('input', evt => {
  document.querySelector('.img-row').style.height = evt.target.value + 'px';
})
```

```css
body {
  background: silver;
  margin: 1em;
}

.img-row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
}

.img-row > img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Wait for it ... images can be slow to load ...</p>

<p>Adjust row height: <input id="i1" type="range" min="50" max="300" value="50" step="50"></p>

<div class="img-row">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" title="1:1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" title="3:2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180" title="16:9">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/240/180" title="4:3">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/99/176" title="9:16"> <!-- portrait -->
</div>
```

Did you use the **full page** link?

Now the only remaining challenge is to *dynamically adjust the height of the flexbox* so that the images exactly fill the width of the screen. If we can determine the *aspect ratio* that the flexbox needs to have, we can use that together with the viewport width to calculate our desired height.

Fortunately, if we know the aspect ratios of each of the images in the row, we simply need to sum these ratios to obtain the aspect ratio when they are arranged beside each other. Let's do this for the five images in our example, which are:

- 1:1 = 1
- 3:2 = 1.5
- 16:9 = 1.777
- 4:3 = 1.333
- 9:16 = 0.5625

Add these up and the result is 6.17. So we simply divide our viewport width (minus the sum of the gaps, if we want gaps) by 6.17 to obtain the desired height of our flexbox.

Here is a snippet which implements this algorithm. It does not depend on knowing the aspect ratios of the images ahead of time, rather it waits for the images to load and then checks their `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`. Note that because it listens for resize events, which are fired rapidly when a browser window is stretched with a mouse, we need to [debounce](https://medium.com/@akhilanand.ak01/understanding-debounce-in-javascript-efficient-event-handling-d1d883628c6c) for performance reasons.

Again, after running the snippet please use the **full page** link and adjust the size of your browser window to test the responsiveness.

```js
let debounceTimer

const recalc = () => {
  const imgRow = document.querySelector('.img-row')
  const images = Array.from(imgRow.children)

  const colGap = 5   // 5 pixels, to match the column-gap on .img-row
  const totalGap = (images.length - 1) * colGap

  let ratioSum = 0
  images.forEach(img => {
    ratioSum += img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight
    img.style.opacity = "1"
  })
  imgRow.style.height = ((imgRow.offsetWidth - totalGap) / ratioSum) + 'px'
}

// run this when all the images have finished loading, so we have access to their intrinsic sizes
addEventListener('load', () => {
  recalc()
})

addEventListener('resize', () => {
  clearTimeout(debounceTimer)
  if (document.readyState === "complete")
    debounceTimer = setTimeout(recalc, 200)
})
```

```css
body {
  background: silver;
  margin: 1em;
}

.img-row {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;       /* initial value, overridden by script */
  transition: 300ms;
}

.img-row > img {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;         /* initial value, overridden by script */
}
```

```html
<p>Wait for it ... images can be slow to load ...</p>
<div class="img-row">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" title="1:1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" title="3:2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/180" title="16:9">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/240/180" title="4:3">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/99/176" title="9:16"> <!-- portrait -->
</div>
```

Did you use the **full page** link?

For further reading, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77346865/2518285).

[image]